# How to output data from a directive to a controller, and should I?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

#### Use case

For use in a form, I created a directive that tracks changes in an array. It allows changes to be reverted and deletions and additions to be stored separately. It allows for an array (one to many mapping in the database) to be updated incrementally (rather than requiring the server to either diff, or rewrite the entire list).

---

#### Problem?

My question is about the way I expose the functionality to the controller's scope. I currently use an two-way databound attribute on the directive's scope. This works, and it seems reliable (of course you can easily break it by reassigning the scope's value, but intentionally you can break anything).

---

#### Code

You can see this **[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z92EL08vNLzZPMh30H9k?p=preview)** to see this in action. It allows methods on the directive's controller to be called from the view and the view's controller. (I am using the directive controller intentionally because that's what I do in my actual code for the directive to directive communication, but this could also just be placed in the linking function.)

---

#### Question

Is this way of doing it bad design? Am I completely throwing AngularJS out of the window now and hacking in my own code. Are there any better ways to expose functions from a directive (keep in mind that there'll be multiple of these in a single form).

It's very easy to pass in `my-attribute="someFunction()"` to have the directive be a consumer of the view controller. I can't find a better way to do the opposite and have the view controller consume from the directive.

---

#### Alternative?

I've been thinking about using a service here, in which the service will provide an object that is instanciated in the view, passed to the directive, and have the directive blurp out it's results to that object. Then in turn have the view controller consume the information from that service's object. Would this be a better approach?

Comment: do you really need the isolated scope? If it wasn't isolated would have same scope as controller. Can still create functions, manipulate data etc within directive . With same scope can use attributes to define data, just use `$scope[$attrs.someAttribute]` notatation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach. In fact built-in angular directives such as ng-form use this approach to store the controller in the scope (see the name property of ng-form)  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngForm

For more re-usability though I would put the api methods on the controller and then put the controller itself in the api:

```
this.getChanges = function () {};
this.resetChanges = function(){};

$scope.api = this;
```

In directives, the main purpose of the controller is to serve as an api for other directives (if you didn't need an api for other directives you could just do everything in the link function). Doing it this way ensures the api is available both on the scope as well as to any directive that 'requires' the `oneToMany` directive.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. I use another directive on the ng-repeat for each child that talks to the common parent directive. So therefore I use the controller function :).